# Giving a search term a yellow background color

Tags: php, css

The function below puts a search term `$find` in bold.  It works just fine.  However, I would like to make it so that instead of putting `$find` in bold, it gives it a yellow background, as in the CSS property `background-color:#FFFF00;`.  How could I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

The function:

```
function highlight($text, $words) {
    preg_match_all('~\w+~', $words, $m);
    if(!$m)
        return $text;
    $re = '~\\b(' . implode('|', $m[0]) . ')\\b~i';
    return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
}
```

The PHP/HTML:

```
echo '<td class="sitename1search"><a href="http://www...com>'.highlight($row["title"], $find)).'</a></td>';
```

The CSS:

```
.sitename1search { width: 800px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 12px;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #000000;
            padding-bottom: 0px;

}

.sitename1search a{ width: 350px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 12px;
            overflow:hidden !important;
            color: #004284;
            padding-bottom: 0px;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
return preg_replace($re, '<b>$0</b>', $text);
```

With

```
return preg_replace($re, '<span style="background-color:#FFFF00;">$0</span>', $text);
```

Answer (score 5):

Just add the `class` attribute in your PHP:

```
function highlight($text, $words) {

    // your php code
    return preg_replace($re, '<span class="found-term">$0</span>', $text); // changed line
}
```

and add this to your CSS file:

```
.found-term { 
  background-color:#FFFF00;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

It's better than `style` attributte in PHP - simply because clashing of logic and design is mostly bad idea.

Comment: +1. This one is slightly better, as it keeps HTML and CSS seperate (which is always best practice).

Comment: +1: I'd just update your answer so your b's class "founded-term" matches the css "found-term".  Also, a span is probably more semantically correct here.